# C# аналог функции друг C++

Tags: c#

Помогите решить проблему: класс A наследуется от класса B, a у класса C есть один метод который должен быть доступен только классу A. Как это реализовать средствами C# (.NET 3.5)?

---

Класс C это мой синглтон, который инициализируется один раз с участием класса A (из класса A передаётся параметр), и я бы хотел сделать что бы другие классы ничего не знали про тот метод c параметром в классе C который создаёт этот единственный экземпляр класса C, а для них был доступен только метод на получения объекта синглтона.

---

класс A это класс в файле Global.asax (своего рода глобального класса приложения) так мне сказали что бы я при аутентификации подгружал данные для вошедшего пользователя (с условием загружать их не в сессию)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В C# нету прямого аналога декларации `friend` из C++. Тем не менее, вы можете попробовать альтернативы:

1. Почему класс `A` должен вообще иметь доступ к приватным методам класса `C`, если они друг к другу не имеют никакого отношения? Может быть, на самом деле класс `A` -- внутренний класс класса `C`? Объявите его внутри, будет доступ к внутренним методам.
2. Может быть, класс `A` -- часть тестовой системы, он *тестирует* класс `C`? Тогда объявите нужный метод как `internal`, и поставьте атрибут `InternalsVisibleTo` у основной сборки, ссылающийся на тестовую сборку.
3. Если уж совсем никак по-другому нельзя, воспользуйтесь рефлексией.

---

А вообще, объясните, чего вы хотите добиться семантически, вполне может оказаться, что вы идёте неправильным путём.

Comment: @минусатор: не сочтите за труд объяснить ваш минус.

Comment: Хейтеры в своем стиле, они не будут объяснять.

Comment: Класс C это мой синглтон, который инициализируется один раз с участием класса A (из класса A передаётся параметр), и я бы хотел сделать что бы другие классы ничего не знали про тот метод c параметром в классе C который создаёт этот единственный экземпляр класса C, а для них был доступен только метод на получения объекта синглтона.

Comment: @romandrovich: это обычно плохая идея, разрешить классу знать слишком много о других классах, теряется инкапсуляция, то есть весь смысл классов. Поэтому расскажите, почему для инициализации _из_ `A` вам нужен доступ к `C` _для_ `A`. Является ли класс `A` по сути "куском" `C`? Тогда так его и объявляйте. Если `A` имеет применение и вне инициализации `C`, он будет уметь слишком много, разбейте его на части.

Comment: Сделайте "ленивый" конструктор с выдёргиванием значения из свойства класса А когда создаётся объект.

Comment: @VladD: класс A это класс в файле Global.asax (своего рода глобального класса приложения) так мне сказали что бы я при аутентификации подгружал данные для вошедшего пользователя (с условием загружать их не в сессию)

Comment: @romandrovich: пока всё хорошо, а для чего вам гарантия, что только `A` сможет запустить создание `C`? Завтра вы можете поменять общую логику запуска. Вам на самом деле нужна не эта гарантия, а другая -- что запуск создания `C` будет выполнен _ровно один раз_. Этого нельзя добиться на уровне синтаксиса, так что просто выбрасывайте исключение, если функция будет вызвана второй раз.

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Это плохой дизайн, скорее всего.

Answer (score 1):

Класс "С" наследуется от какого-то из этих классов? Если да, повесьте protected на метод который нужно дёргать от "А", если нет - можно проще - сделайте объект класса "А" как поле класса "С" и дёргайте когда захотите.

Comment: Нет мне наоборот надо бы унаследовать A от C и дёрнуть из A метод из C, но унаследовать нельзя т.к. нет множественного наследования!

Comment: Если метод не работает со внутренними полями класса "С" сделайте Интерфейс, который реализует нужный вам метод и отнаследуйтесь для классов "А" и "С"